# Italics in Text Menu Field

Tags: navigation

I am building a menu that contains the titles of books.  This would normally be coded as

```
<cite>Book Name</cite>
```

in html.  The Menu Link Title portion of the menu is a Text field which does not format html tags.

Is there a way to place the Book Names in Italics given that Menu Link Title is a Text field?